# How to determine the dynamic response of a spring-mass system?

Tags: transfer-function, frequency-response, homework

**The Problem**

I have the following system for which I would like to determine its dynamic response, taken from [these lecture notes](https://engweb.swan.ac.uk/%7Eadhikaris/TeachingPages/DampedVibration.pdf) pg.20:

[image: spring-mass_system]

where the forcing functions are $u_1 = 1-U(t - t_0)$, $u_2=0$, and $u_3=0$, $U(\cdot)$ is the unit step function and $t_0 = 2\pi/\omega_1$ where $\omega_1$ is the first undamped natural frequency.

---

**My Attempt**

I know the time domain representation of the system to be of the typical format as shown in Eq.(1), and therefore the Fourier transform is as shown in Eq.(2):

\begin{gather}
   \mathbf{M}\ddot{\mathbf{x}} + \mathbf{C}\dot{\mathbf{x}} + \mathbf{Kx} = \mathbf{u}(t) \tag{1} \\
%
   \Rightarrow [-\omega^2\mathbf{M} + i\omega\mathbf{C} + \mathbf{K}]\mathbf{X}(i\omega) = \mathbf{U}(i\omega) \tag{2}
\end{gather}

where since we know that $\mathcal{L}\{1 - U(t - t_0)\} = 1 - \frac{\exp{(-st_0})}{s}$, then the Fourier transform of the right hand side of Eq.(2) is:

$$\mathbf{U}(i\omega) = \left[\left(1 - \frac{e^{-i\omega t_0}}{i\omega}\right),\, 0,\, 0,\right]^T$$

As a result, the dynamic response would be:

$$\mathbf{X}(i\omega) = [-\omega^2\mathbf{M} + i\omega\mathbf{C} + \mathbf{K}]^{-1}\mathbf{U}(i\omega) \tag{3}$$

Since the response by which I am comparing my answer is given in generalised modal coordinates $\mathbf{q}$, then the modal transformation of Eq.(3) follows where $\mathbf{V}$ is the eigenvector matrix thus we know that the modal mass, stiffness, damping matrices should be $\bar{\mathbf{M}} = \mathbf{I}$ (i.e. the identity matrix), $\bar{\mathbf{K}} = \mathbf{\Omega}^2$ (i.e. a diagonal marix containing the square of the natural frequencies), and $\bar{\mathbf{C}} = \mathbf{V}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{V}$ respectively. So Eq.(3) becomes:

$$\mathbf{q}(i\omega) = \left[-\omega^2\mathbf{I} + i\omega\bar{\mathbf{C}} + \mathbf{\Omega}^2 \right]^{-1}\left[\mathbf{V}^T\mathbf{U}(i\omega)\right] \tag{4}$$

Thefore, the dynamic response would be the magnitude of the imaginary numbers obtained from Eq.(4) above, for all positive $\omega$.

However, when I follow the above steps and solve the problem in `MATLAB`, the answer is far from the one provided in the excercise. Admitedly, the code is very simple as well (see below) so I struggle to see where I could have gone wrong:

```
clear ; clc

% Input
n = 3 ;         % Number of DOFs
m = 1 ;         % Mass [kg]
k = 1 ;         % Stiffnes [N/m]
c = 0.2 ;       % Viscous damping [Ns/m]
nv = [1 0 0]' ; % Load application vector (load applied to 1st DOF)

% Matrices
M = diag(m*ones(n, 1)) ;
K = diag(2*k*ones(n,1)) - diag(k*ones(n-1,1),-1) - diag(k*ones(n-1,1),1) ;
C = diag(c*ones(n,1)) ;

% Undamped Natural Frequencies & Modes
[V, Omsq] = eig(K, M) ;
Om = diag(sqrt(abs(Omsq))) ; % Natural Frequencies

% Frequency Aanalysis
t0 = 2*pi/Om(1) ;           % Time where unit step is applied
omega = linspace(0, 3, 100) ; % Frequency vector

for i = 1:numel(omega)
    
    s = 1i*omega(i) ;
    
    Us = V'*((1 - exp(-s*t0)/s)*nv) ;
    FRF(:,i) = (s^2*eye(n) + s*(V'*C*V) + Omsq)\Us ;
end

% Plotting
figure ; plot(omega, abs(FRF)) ; grid on ; set(gca, 'YScale', 'log') ; ylim([0 10]) ;
```

[image]

Comment: Since this infolves frequency analysis and frequency response functions, I figured I might find an audience here, but your suggestion seems to make sense. Would you know if I can transfer this question there or do I need to repost from the beginning?

Comment: Actually you have at least a frequency analysis mistake, and a programming error here...

Comment: Migrated here at the request of the author.

Comment: @PeterK. It's definetely fitting for control theory, and the closest site probably i *robotics.se*, but this place, or dsp.se could also work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TimWescott indicated, this problem is more suitable for **control theory** for a fuller understanding than for digital signal processing, yet there's no *control.se* as far as I know. Hence you can give it a try here too since such damped-spring systems is not uncommon subject for audio / acoustic engineers etc.

First of all you have a programming error: Your for-loop variable is set to **i** , a potential error because there's already the **complex unit** $j$ in your body code in the line $$s = j \omega \tag{1}$$which you have implemented as :

`s = 1i*omega(i)`

which is wrong: you are using the same letter **i** , both for indexing integer into the angular frequency vector **omega**, and also for the imaginary unit $j$. I've replaced the for-loop variable with **k** instead.

Second, you have a signal processing mistake. Your nonzero input function is $$ u_1(t) = 1 - u(t-t_0) \tag{2}$$whose (bilateral - double sided) Laplace transform is

$$ - \frac{ e^{ -s t_0} }{s} \tag{3} $$

You can see this by noting that the input is actually: $$u_1(t) = u(t_0 - t) \tag{4}$$

And the third issue is about the diagonalized computation. I'have replaced the diagonalised frequency response calculation, with the undiagonalised one with the matrcices **M**,**K**, **C**. The result is improved,as shown on the plot below, but still not exactly what you have been given as the answer plot. I guess you may correct it further.

I put the corrected code and the corresponding MATLAB output below :

```
clc; clear variables ; close all

% Input
n = 3 ;         % Number of DOFs
m = 1 ;         % Mass [kg]
k = 1 ;         % Stiffnes [N/m]
c = 0.2 ;       % Viscous damping [Ns/m]
nv = [1 0 0]' ; % Load application vector (load applied to 1st DOF)

% Matrices
M = diag(m*ones(n, 1)) ;
K = diag(2*k*ones(n,1)) - diag(k*ones(n-1,1),-1) - diag(k*ones(n-1,1),1) ;
C = diag(c*ones(n,1)) ;

% Undamped Natural Frequencies & Modes
[V, Omsq] = eig(K,M); 
Om = diag(sqrt(abs(Omsq))) ; % Natural Frequencies

% Frequency Aanalysis
t0 = 2*pi/Om(1) ;           % Time where unit step is applied
omega = linspace(0, 2.5, 100) ; % Frequency vector

for k = 1:numel(omega)
    
    s = 1i*omega(k) ;
           
    Us = -(exp(-s*t0)/s)*nv; 
    FRF(:,k) = (s^2*M + s*C + K)\Us ;

    %Us = V'*((1 - exp(-s*t0)/s)*nv) ;
    %FRF(:,k) = (s^2*eye(n) + s*(V'*C*V) + Omsq)\Us ;

end

% Plotting
figure ; plot(omega, abs(FRF)) ; grid on ; set(gca, 'YScale', 'log') ; ylim([0.01 10]) ;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the above. There's one thing I don't get though; why do you calculate the undamped natural frequencies using `eig(M, C)` instead of `eig(K, M)` ?

Comment: Sorry, say it's a typo there. Indeed. Btw, when I've written the answer I hadn't actually read the link you've posted. Indeed now I see that, the author gave an explicit solution of the problem you ask. Yet he doesn't provide a matlab code for the simulation? Furthermore, I see that his definition of input u1(t) is problematic: 1-u(t-t0) or u(t)-u(t-t0) ? He writes the 1st, but seems to mean the 2nd: left ambigious. Hence he should have provided the **code** so that we could really see it. May be he used different settings in his simulation. Also the Modal approach shoul yield the same result.

Comment: "I see that his definition of input u1(t) is problematic: 1-u(t-t0) or u(t)-u(t-t0) ?".  Yup.  Particularly when you're dealing with the Fourier transform.  If you're playing with the single-sided Laplace transform, it's safe to assume that "x(t) = 1" really means "x(t) = u(t)".  But the Fourier transform is always two-sided, so a signal *could* really be 1 from $t = -\infty$ until $t = t_0$, and zero thereafter, not (as the author probably intended) $x(t) = 1$ for $0 \le t < t_0$ and zero everywhere else.  In the latter case, $x(t) = u(t) - u(t - t_0)$.

Comment: @TimWescott  exactly, if he already has $u(t)$ in the formula then it should be $u(t)-u(t-t_0)$, rather than the ambiguous $1 - u(t-t_0)$ if he means a causal input definition, etc...